# ¿Cómo exportar un data.frame de R a Excel?

Tags: r, excel

Tengo un data frame realmente enorme que genere en R y necesito analizarlo en otro programa que lo necesita en Excel (VCE para ser específicos), no sé como puedo exportarlo de R a Excel, busqué tutoriales pero no logro entender..

Espero puedan ayudarme!

Muchísimas gracias...

Comment: Lamentablemente las recomendaciones de herramientas, paquetes o librerías suelen terminar cerradas ya que se consideran basadas en opiniones. ¿Excel? ¿Qué formato xls, xlsx? ¿Un csv no alcanza? Revisa este enlace: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-xlsx-package-a-quick-start-guide-to-manipulate-excel-files-in-r, tal ve te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

este código, te pueda ser de utilidad

```
    library(openxlsx)
mydata <- write.xlsx(mydata,".xlsx")
saveWorkbook(mydata, file = "C:/nombre_del_archivo.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Cuando pongas la dirección del archivo por lo regular esta como `\` por lo que debes cambiarlo a `/` para evitar un error, también poner el nombre con terminación .`xlsx`. `mydata` <- son tus datos que quieres exportar de R.

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jorge!!!! me funcionó, solo que cambie a `file="nombre_del_archivo.xlsx" ` porque si lo ponia con `C:/`me daba error ... Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!